# NSUserActivity for directions not working

Tags: ios, nsuseractivity

I'm having some trouble implementing an NSUserActivity with a mapItem from my app.

All I want is to be able to use the "Get Directions" suggestion in the app switcher, like Foursquare does:

[image]

I'm using the following code in my `viewDidLoad` method, in the view controller which displays the location (a pub) I want to register.

```
NSUserActivity *activity = [[NSUserActivity alloc] initWithActivityType:@"co.pubmapper.ViewPub"];

CLLocationCoordinate2D coords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.pub.lat, self.pub.lng);
MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coords];
MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
[mapItem setName:self.pub.name];
activity.mapItem = mapItem;

// not sure any of these are necessary for my use case
[activity setEligibleForSearch:YES];
[activity setEligibleForHandoff:YES];
[activity setEligibleForPublicIndexing:YES];

[activity becomeCurrent];
```

When this runs I see the following in the console:

```
[main] sendUserActivityToServer, called on activity C626E4B1-ADF8-49D8-80FB-C773DB71243D after it had been invalidated, so doing nothing.
```

Which suggests my `activity` item is being invalidated immediately for some reason. I added the following to set the `expirationDate` but still get the same message in the console.

```
activity.expirationDate = [NSDate distantFuture];
```

As far as I can tell I've followed everything in the docs here https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsuseractivity?language=objc

I've also added my activity type to `NSUserActivityTypes` , although I think this is only strictly necessary for launching my app and receiving an activity object, which is not what i'm concerned with right now.

SOLVED: based on correct answer from @raidfive below, `activity` is now a class property with a strong reference:

```
@property (strong) NSUserActivity *activity;
...
[_activity becomeCurrent];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if this applies to `mapItem` types, but the docs mention:

> Your app must maintain a strong reference to any activity objects that you use for search results.

So maybe you need to store `activity` as a class level variable.

Comment: BINGO! Thanks a lot. I had read that at one point, but probably dismissed as only relevant to full Spotlight search results. It appears it is in fact needed for this use case too. Cheers!

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear.